# Lookup and fetch multiple delimited partner names

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have list of partner name codes, delimited by space. Like the one shown in below,

[image]

I have another table(`E:F`), from where I have to map them to show the partner names like the column C, perhaps i am not able to understand how to make it happen,

I have tried using this formula which brings only one partner name but when there are multiple it does not shows up, do i need to add another function like TEXTJOIN or what I am doing wrong here.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,JOIN("|",FILTER($E$2:$E,$E$2:$E<>""))),""),$E$2:$F,2,0),"")
```

Link To [GS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-ICBL470OyhWRJPv1ulhdMG-6rSyqEmLuW03S4Gb5s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I recommend that you share a link to your sample spreadsheet shown in your post. An image may be helpful for *understanding*, but it gives the volunteer contributors here no  simple starting data to work with or place to build/test solutions. In order to start from your image only, volunteers would need to spend their own time building your data set themselves, and that will be a deterrent to many. Help us help you by sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my sheet ("Erik Help"). The following formula is in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"PARTNER NAMES";IF(A2:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A2:A," ",0,1),D:E,2,FALSE)&",")),,COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2:A," ",0,1))))),",$",""))})`

This one formula produces the header (which you can change within the formula itself as you like) and all results for all rows.

`IF(A2:A="",,...)` means if a cell in Col A is blank, then the result in the same row of Col B will also be blank (i.e., null).

`SPLIT` (the first time in the formula) will split the Col-A values at the spaces.

`VLOOKUP` will try to find each split value in the D:E list. If found, the full name will replace the initials. If not found, `IFERROR` will return null.

You will see `&","`. That is appending a comma to any full names that are returned.

`TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE...),,COLUMNS()))` is what many call "QUERY Smash." It basically, flips the remaining results of the `VLOOKUP` into columns instead of rows, turns everything into headers (to get them in one cell per column) and then flips them back to row orientation.

`TRIM` gets rid of spaces where no names were found in the full list.

`REGEXREPLACE(... ,",$","")` replaces any final comma that has no name after it with null.